# SelectedIndexChanged triggered not consistent

Tags: asp.net, ascx, selectedindexchanged

I have a `RadComboBox` on an ascx that is used as both a control in a inline page as well as a in a popup. The selectedindexchanged is triggered within the inline page instance but not in the popup. Why?

Comment: It is a windowless popup that loads a aspx page which has the ascx control attached to it but using: "window.open"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do with the RadComboBox  in conjuction with RadScriptManager not being loaded properly